# Using multiple TTL values in Cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, ttl, data-compaction

What are the disadvantages of using multiple TTL values(One in table level and another for specific data rows to override the TTL for those rows) in Cassandra table.Will it result into incomplete data cleanup?
As in TWCS being used,we may never get sstables with all rows where tombstones are expired and sstables could be dropped.

What are the best ways to overcome this issue.We are thinking of segregate data to have unique TTL for same table rows.Any other thougths please (V3.11.5 being used)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to https://dba.stackexchange.com instead. But don't be concerned, I'm just letting you know for future reference. Cheers!